Publish SonarQube Coverage Report for Set of Files
I have these below Tasks in my Gated.YML file which generates and Publishes the coverage in SonarQube Portal as below


task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
displayName: “Run DI.Apps.Services tests”
inputs:
command: test
projects: “**/Test.IP.Apps.Tests/*.csproj”
arguments: ‘–no-restore --configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --collect “Code coverage”’

task: SonarQubePrepare@4
displayName: Prepare analysis on SonarQube
inputs:
SonarQube: icsp.sonarqube
projectKey: ‘$(Build.DefinitionName)’
projectName: ‘$(Build.DefinitionName)’
extraProperties: |
sonar.qualitygate.wait=true
sonar.qualitygate.timeout=3000 sonar.cs.opencover.reportsPaths=$(Build.SourcesDirectory)//TestResults//coverage.opencover.xml
task: SonarQubeAnalyze@4
displayName: ‘Run Code Analysis’

task: SonarQubePublish@4
displayName: ‘Publish Quality Gate Result’




I want to generate code coverage modulewise Like TestModule for some set of like below files and Publish that Module Coverage in SonarQube
IP.Apps.Services\src\Test.IP.Apps.Business\TestProcessors*
IP.Apps.Services\src\Test.IP.Apps.API.Rest\Controllers\ModuleController.cs
If anyone can point me into right direction?
